# Binding WPF children grid to parent

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I have an application with the following model with a parent class job and children jobRequirements.

I'm using mvvm light and a view model.  The form has three sections.  one is a datagrid with all the jobs.  The user selects a job which triggers a selectedjob in the view model.

The selectedjob's properties are displayed in text boxes and a datagrid is displayed for the children JobRequirements.

JobRequirements is bound to the selectedjob.jobRequirements.

For existing jobrequirements everything works as expected.

The jobRequirement datagrid, however,  will not bind to a new job. The user has to actively add it using code in the viewModel.  This system works but is there a way for it to work using just the XAML?

That is can I add a new job and have the requirement data grid know that the requirements being added are added to the new job?

Model:

```
 public class Job  
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Int64 id { get; set; }

    public string jobshortname { get; set; }  

    public  virtual ObservableCollection<JobRequirement> jobRequirements { get; set; }
```

}

```
  public class JobRequirement

{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int64 id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("job")]
    public Int64 Jobid { get; set; }
     public DateTime deadline { get; set; } 
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public virtual  Job job { get; set; }
    public virtual  Requirement requirement { get; set; }
}
```

View Model:

```
  public class jobViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private DataService _ds;
    public const string jobscPropertyName = "jobsc";
    public const string jobrequirementsPropertyName = "requirements";
    private ObservableCollection<Requirement> _requirements ;
    public ObservableCollection<Requirement> requirements
    {
        get
        {
            return _requirements;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_requirements == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _requirements = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(jobrequirementsPropertyName);
        }
    }

   private ObservableCollection<Job> _jobsc;
    public ObservableCollection<Job> jobsc
    {
        get { return _jobsc; }
        set
        {
            if (_jobsc == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _jobsc = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(jobscPropertyName);
        }
    }
    public const string selectedJobPropertyName = "selectedJob";
    private Job _selectedJob ;
    public Job selectedJob
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedJob;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedJob == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _selectedJob = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(selectedJobPropertyName);
        }
    }
    public RelayCommand NewJob { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand SaveJob { get; private set; }
     public RelayCommand Newjr { get; private set; }
    public jobViewModel(DataService ds)
    {
        _ds = ds;
        NewJob = new RelayCommand(getnewjob);
        SaveJob = new RelayCommand(savejob);
        Newjr = new RelayCommand(addRequirement);
        requirements = _ds.getAllRequirements();
        jobsc = ds.GetAllJobs();     
    }
    private void addRequirement()
    {
        JobRequirement jr = new JobRequirement();
        jr.Jobid = selectedJob.id;
        jr.deadline = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1);
        selectedJob.jobRequirements.Add(jr);
    }
  private async void savejob()
    {   
        selectedJob = await _ds.saveJob(selectedJob);
    }
    private void getnewjob()
    {
       selectedJob = new Models.Job();
        jobsc.Add(selectedJob);
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant XAML

```
  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,10,0">
    <DataGrid x:Name="jobDataGrid" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" DockPanel.Dock="Left"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding jobsc}" Grid.Row="1" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding selectedJob, Mode=TwoWay}"  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" CanUserAddRows="False"
       >         
        <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idColumn" Binding="{Binding id}" Header="id" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="jobshortnameColumn" Binding="{Binding jobshortname}" Header="jobshortname" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
           <DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
        <Grid x:Name="jrframe" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Grid.Row="0">
         <--Button to add new requirement -->
                <Button x:Name="jrbutton" Content="New" Command="{Binding Newjr}"/>
            </StackPanel>
<-- Requirement Grid -->
    <DataGrid x:Name="jobRequirementsDataGrid"  Grid.Row="1" CanUserAddRows="False"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding selectedJob.jobRequirements, Mode=TwoWay}"   RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="commentColumn" Binding="{Binding comment}" Header="comment" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="deadlineColumn" Header="deadline" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker  SelectedDate="{Binding deadline, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idColumn1" Binding="{Binding id}" Header="id" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="JobidColumn" Binding="{Binding Jobid}"  />

           </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
            <Grid x:Name="grid1" DataContext="{Binding selectedJob, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>                   
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>                  
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBox x:Name="idTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding id, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
               <Label Content="jobshortname:" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="jobshortnameTextBox" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding jobshortname, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
                          </Grid>
        </StackPanel>


    </DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Binding Requirement Grid ItemSource to selectedJob instead of selectedJob.jobRequirements.

```
<-- Requirement Grid -->
<DataGrid x:Name="jobRequirementsDataGrid"  Grid.Row="1" CanUserAddRows="False"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding selectedJob, Mode=TwoWay}"   RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="commentColumn" Binding="{Binding jobRequirements.comment}" Header="comment" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="deadlineColumn" Header="deadline" Width="SizeToHeader">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DatePicker  SelectedDate="{Binding jobRequirements.deadline, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idColumn1" Binding="{Binding jobRequirements.id}" Header="id" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="JobidColumn" Binding="{Binding jobRequirements.Jobid}"  />

       </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't work.  The jobRequirements datagrid becomes completely empty and non responsive.

Comment: Is the second grid empty even if a job is selected in the first grid?

Comment: Yes the second grid is empty even if there is an existing record.  It also does not have an empty row even if canUserAddRow=true.  I also don't see the logic in how this would work as the ItemsSource would be a single object as opposed to a collection which it should be looking for.